# Using python mock to count number of method calls

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'm just starting out using the python mocking framework. I'd like to just count the number of times a method gets called, without removing the effects of actually calling the method.

For example, in this simple counter example, I would like to **both** increment the counter and track that it was called:

```
import unittest
import mock


class Counter(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0

    def increment(self):
        self.count += 1


class CounterTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_increment(self):
        c = Counter()
        c.increment()
        self.assertEquals(1, c.count)

    def test_call_count(self):

        with mock.patch.object(Counter, 'increment') as fake_increment:
            c = Counter()
            self.assertEquals(0, fake_increment.call_count)
            c.increment()
            self.assertEquals(1, fake_increment.call_count)

            # increment() didn't actually get called.
            self.assertEquals(1, c.count)  # Fails.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Is it possible to force `mock` to call the mocked method after it registered the call, or just signify that I want to keep the effects of the mocked function?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use wraps:

```
c = Counter()
with mock.patch.object(Counter, 'increment', wraps=c.increment) as fake_increment:
```

There can be some binding problems if you initialize `c` later, as the function passed to `wraps` won't know about `self`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not super experienced in mock<sup>1</sup>, but I accomplished it by using a function wrapper rather than the default `MagicMock`:

```
class FuncWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.call_count = 0
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.call_count += 1
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)

class CounterTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_call_count(self):

        c = Counter()
        new_call = FuncWrapper(c.increment)
        with mock.patch.object(c, 'increment', new=new_call) as fake_increment:
            print fake_increment
            self.assertEquals(0, fake_increment.call_count)
            c.increment()
            self.assertEquals(1, fake_increment.call_count)

            self.assertEquals(1, c.count)  # Fails.
```

Of course, this `FuncWrapper` is pretty minimal.  It just counts the calls and then delegates flow control back to the original function.  If you need to test other things at the same time, you'd need to add to the `FuncWrapper` class.  I've also just patched a class instance rather than the entire class.  The main reason for that is because I needed an instance method in `FuncWrapper`.

<sup><sup>1</sup>In fact, I just started to learn -- Consider yourself warned ;-).</sup>