# how to mock the output of a mock object in pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I have this function:

```
def get_sf_connection(usr, acc, key_path, vwh, db):
    with open(f"{key_path}", "rb") as key:
        p_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(
            key.read(), password=None, backend=default_backend()
        )

    pkb = p_key.private_bytes(
        encoding=serialization.Encoding.DER,
        format=serialization.PrivateFormat.PKCS8,
        encryption_algorithm=serialization.NoEncryption(),
    )
   return pkb
```

How I can test that `p_key.private_bytes` has been called once?

This is the unit test I wrote so far:

```
@patch("builtins.open", new_callable=mock_open)
def test_get_private_key(mock_open, mocker, key_path="my/path"):
    mocker.patch.object(subject, "serialization")
    subject._get_private_key(key_path)
    mock_open.assert_called_with(key_path, "rb")
    subject.serialization.load_pem_private_key.assert_called_once()
```

Comment: Have you tried `subject.serialization.load_pem_private_key.return_value.private_bytes.called_once()`?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps you, this is a rudimentary approach using decorators :

```py
# decorator for counting f calls
def fcounter(f):
    def helper(*args,**kwargs):
        helper.calls+=1
        return f(*args,**kwargs)
    helper.calls=0
    helper.__name__=f.__name__
    return helper

# afterwards you can wrap p_key.private_bytes
pkb = fcounter(p_key.private_bytes)

# and then call it and count the number of calls using calls attribute
pkb()

# get no of calls
pkb.calls
```

Also you can take a look here maybe you can find something usefully :
[Using python mock to count number of method calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22356914/using-python-mock-to-count-number-of-method-calls)